# Where did the "Near East" go to?

Tags: word-choice

I was reading some essays the other day written in the late 1940s and early 1950s, in which the phrase *Near East* (meaning Syria, Lebanon, Jordan, etc) recurred quite frequently. It then occurred to me that I hadn't heard that name recently, as it seems to have been replaced by *Middle East*.

So I wonder: when, and why, did the *Near East* become the *Middle East*? It hasn't moved, after all.

Comment: No, but we did. The Near East became the Middle East when the United States (and the Western Hemisphere in general) came to be considered fully part of the global community. See [the NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Near+East%2CMiddle+East&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), which shows, unsurprisingly, the latter surpassing the former around the beginning of WWII.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_East may be of interest.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_East) covers this quite well.

Comment: We are into geopolitical terminology on englishSE?

Comment: If the Mid-East is Jordan and Syria and thereabouts, and the Mid-West is that part of the United States between the Mississipi River and the Rocky Mountains, then the "Center" must be around the Azores, I think. And why do we never talk about the "Mid-South" and the "Far South"? They should be, like Congo/Tanzania and Zimbabwe/South Africa, no?

Comment: Thanks to all for you comments and answers. I think Robusto has it; I had heard before of "stationary international travel", but here we have some stationary continental drift.

Comment: @Jay Actually in the US [the Midwest starts as far east as Ohio and going west stops at Kansas, not reaching the Rockies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midwestern_United_States#History_of_the_term_Midwest).

Comment: If you care about precision and tradition, you will probably use *Near East* for Egypt–Turkey–Iraq–Arabia, *Middle East* for Iran–Kazakhstan, *Far East* for Burma–Japan. *North Africa* is Morocco–Egypt, obviously. The *Arab World* is where they speak Arabic, so Morocco–Iraq–Arabia. The *Muslim World* is wherever they are Muslim, obviously, so a rather large and diverse region.

Comment: @Cerberus: That depends on your point of view, i.e., whether you are located in the West or the East. ^_^

Comment: @Robusto: Sure, it only makes sense from a Western perspective. If I lived in Turkmenistan, I would not use any of those relative terms!

Answer (score 3):

The Middle East or Mideast is a region that encompasses Western Asia and Northern Africa.The term is considered to be Eurocentric and used as a synonym for Near East, in opposition to Far East. The corresponding adjective is Middle-Eastern and the derived noun is Middle-Easterner.

[Middle East](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_East)

[Near East](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_East)

Comment: Hmm, I've never understood the term "Mid-East" to include northern Africa, other than Egypt. Or maybe that's what they mean. But you wouldn't call Libya, Tunisia, and Morocco part of the "Mid-East", would you? Obviously culturally related since ca AD 650, but ...